# jquery .post data not show

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

**HTML**

```
<input type='button' class='btn btn-success update' value='Update' name='update' >
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
            var id;
            var car_Name;
            var updateThis="update";

            $(".update").on('click', function () {
                $.post("process.php",{id:$(".car_name").attr('rel'),car_name:$(".car_name").val(),updateThis:updateThis},function(data){
                    alert(data);
                });
            });
        });
```

**PHP**

```
if(isset($_POST['updateThis']))
{
    echo $_POST['id']." ".$_POST['car_name'];
}
```

I'm sending data to "process.php" page. I ca not understand about 3rd data "updateThis:updateThis" without this it can not show data.

Comment: is it updateThis="update" is important to use?

Answer (score 0):

What is your php code?
I believe you check `$_POST['updateThis']` in your PHP code and if not set don't show response.